# Possible values for the "java.compiler" system property

Tags: java, jit, jvm-arguments

(I know this is probably a duplicate, but is it almost impossible to search this topic on Google or on SO.)

I know the `java.compiler` system property can take "`NONE`" which disables the JIT compiler, but I am interested in what other values are there and what are their performance characteristics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the early days I believe it was intended that there be competition among external vendors to supply an external .dll/.so named by this property. `symcjit.dll` was the only one I ever encountered. SInce the advent of Hotspot I believe it's obsolete.

Comment: is there somewhere this is documented to be obsolete? The latest current (at this time, JDK 1.8) API documentation for java.lang.Compiler is still worded such that I expect to be able to plug in my own JIT using the java.compiler property, but so-far, no amount of coaxing seems to be working. I can believe it's obsolete, but I'd like to see something from Sun/Oracle that I can rely upon, before giving up on my project.

Answer (score 3):

[`java.compiler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Compiler.html) property is the name of the library to support java native compilers:

> The Compiler class is provided to support Java-to-native-code
>   compilers and related services. By design, the Compiler class does
>   nothing; it serves as a placeholder for a JIT compiler implementation.
>   When the Java Virtual Machine first starts, it determines if the
>   system property java.compiler exists. (System properties are
>   accessible through System.getProperty(String) and
>   System.getProperty(String, String). If so, it is assumed to be the
>   name of a library (with a platform-dependent exact location and type);
>   System.loadLibrary(java.lang.String) is called to load that library.
>   If this loading succeeds, the function named
>   java_lang_Compiler_start() in that library is called.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Oracle published JVM, you should check the property `sun.management.compiler`. A possible value is `HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers`.

You can get this through typing the following command

```
java -server -XshowSettings -version 2>&1 | grep sun.management.compiler
```

If you are using J9 VM published by IBM, a possible value is `jitc`. See [this document](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdk-java-technology/8?topic=compiler-enabling-jit).